# How to reverse digital crown's scrolling direction for SwiftUI ScrollView?

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm building a messenger app with a list being rotated 180 degrees to get that typical messenger look so it scrolls from the bottom. How can I reverse the scrolling direction of the ScrollView so that scrolling feels natural?